# Debian installer screen not shown in Hyper-V Virtual machine at Windows 10

Tags: debian, hyper-v, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 with Hyper-V.
I'm trying to install Debian 11 in a virtual machine.
I am using debian-11.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
I am creating a virtual machine in Hyper-V (generation 1). After starting the VM, I have a Debian screen with no menu. See here:
[Debian installer after boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akCtJ.png)

On a different physical machine with Windows 10 and Hyper-V, I have the same problem.
When first time was run the virtual machine, I would press down arrow key + Enter and I was see next screen of Debian installer (select language). When now run the virtual machine this solution is not work.
What I can do order resolve problem?

Comment: Superuser.com. This site must demonstrate best practices and be in a business environment. Windows 10.... hardly fits that.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot the running VM ( by sending CTRL+ALT+DEL ) and you see (perhaps only for a a second) a ISOLINUX - prompt

Press TAB during this time to see a list of possible boot-options.

I used "install" to start the Debian-Installer in textmode.